# What is the best polyfill for requestAnimationFrame out there?

Tags: css, animation, requestanimationframe, polyfills

I want to use requestAnimationFrame on my mobile web application but also support browsers. Please advise me the best polyfill for requestAnimationFrame out there.

Comment: Perhaps you should just drop ie :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, I use this one: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

But don't expect too much: animation on old browsers is not that good ...

Comment: +1 This rAF shim from Paul Irish works well. But, it's subject to any unfinished loops accumulating and causing slowdowns. So, use it but also fully test your animation code so it can easily complete within the current loop.